# Responsive navigation bar - won't collapse correctly and funky on Drupal

Tags: javascript, html, css, drupal

I've created a responsive navigation bar. I have two problems. 1) When I shrink the screen on my test pages, all of the links don't hide. 2) When I insert the code onto Drupal, it puts the links that are nested in  on a different baseline. It doesn't do that on the test page. I can't figure out a way to create the responsive bar without the button...probably because I'm a beginner.

Here are screenshots for both of the issues[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoPl6.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvCf1.png) and the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Helvetica}

/* Add a background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #486D87;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px; 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

/* Add a background color on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #BE6A14;
    color: white;
}

/* Add a background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #BE6A14;
    color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
 <a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">About Us</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="/about">Store Info</a>
   <a href="/history">History</a>
   <a href="/consignment">Consignment</a>
   <a href="/we-buy-used-books">We Buy Used Books</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a href="/event">Events</a>
 <a href="/blog">Blog</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Signed Firsts</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="/signedfirsts">Signed Fiction</a>
   <a href="/square-non-fiction-subscription">Signed Nonfiction</a>
   <a href="/signed-suspense">Signed Suspense</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a href="/staff-recommendations">Staff Picks</a> 
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Square Books, Jr.</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="/junior">Store Info</a>
   <a href="/junior/history">History</a>
   <a href="/junior/storytime">Storytime</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Gifts</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="/square-books-gifts">
   <a href="/gift-cards">Gift Cards</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a href="/dear-reader-newsletter">Dear Reader</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<script>
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to hide the entire blue nav bar on smaller screens?

Comment: No, I want to keep the blue bar and hide all links except "Home"

Comment: Fixed it...was missing some code. Sorry. Still having issues with the text baseline. Might need to ask our website overlords (middle man between us and drupal...)

Comment: Can you update the code, I can look into the issue.

Comment: Updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will solve your use case:

https://jsfiddle.net/5tof6ry0/4/

Change in css:

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #486D87;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Nah, that didn't work. I think it's the style sheet I'm using. I changed the style sheet for another reason and noticed the problem was fixed, but then my dropdowns wouldn't work. Don't know how to make them work with a different style sheet.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems fine you just need to hide the button element with your media query.

Insert this into your css.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
/*Hide button elements*/
.topnav button, 
.topnav a:not(:first-child) 
{display: none;}
```